# Change localhost to domain (mongodb, nodejs)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, dns, localhost, web-hosting

There is a "template" sort of thing for a shopping like website and I want to make it work on a domain, instead of localhost. The source code is here: https://github.com/jakblak/BestDressed
I already have the domain, and my domain is set up with my VPS so it will run off of that. But again, I would like it to work on the domain instead of localhost. I would also like no port, e.g: localhost:9000

Thanks in advance and sorry if this was a hassle.

Comment: Generally speaking you should just be able to listen on 0.0.0.0:port and you'll be able to get it working. That said, it's not secure to do it this way - you should be using a reverse proxy or load balancer in production. Read up the way AWS or Heroku handle it, two name a couple.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have to install and run this node application on your server and make appropriate configuration changes. After a quick look, it seems you can find them under `server/config/environment/`.
The exact way depends largely on your specific setup.

Comment: What exactly do I change the "localhost" to if my domain is test.com? There is also mongodb connections with localhost, so what's do I change those to?